# Как сделать фон таблицы картинкой?

Tags: html

Нужно чтобы в таблице фон был картинкой т.е. как <body style="background-image:url(tankbg.jpg)">
 *<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">*

Answer (score 1):

```
<table style="background-image:url(tankbg.jpg)"..
```

Что мешает сделать так?

Answer (score 1):

Также как вы написали body через атрибут style.
Пример

```
<table style='background: url("http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png");'><tr><td> тест<br/><br/><br/></td></tr></table>
```